# Why can't I use @android:style/DialogWindowTitle

Tags: android, eclipse

I needed to change title size and simple solution was to create a new style, setting parent to `@android:style/DialogWindowTitle` and then modifiy it. However, Eclipse keep showing an error:

> no resource found

I checked in SDK `styles.xml`, it exists there in every version.

Why can't I override it? I want to use system default for all parameters, and just change the size.

Answer (score 0):

I also got an error while trying to do this:

```
<style name="CenterJustifyDialogTitle" parent="@android:style/DialogWindowTitle" >
         <item name="android:gravity">center|center_vertical</item>
         <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

The error dissapeared when I changed this to:

```
<style name="CenterJustifyDialogTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle" >
         <item name="android:gravity">center|center_vertical</item>
         <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Hope it helps to anyone interested.